# Only getting date in a specified format entered jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to force user to only enter date into text box in a specific format, and don't let them change it at all,

how can I do it, just need right direction.

Here is the fiddle demo,

http://jsfiddle.net/wUpQG/42/

```
var d = new Date();
$('#BirthDate').datepicker({
    changeYear: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    defaultDate: d});
```

HTML

```
Date of Birth (MM/DD/YYYY): <input type="text" class="datepicker minimumSize" name="BirthDate" id="BirthDate"/>
```

I don't want to let user add anything like "abasdjaskdk or 20144 for year etc"

Dont want to make textbox read only, sorry

Comment: http://http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `readonly` of HTML5

```
<input type="text" readonly  class="datepicker minimumSize" name="BirthDate" id="BirthDate" />
```

---

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/6dLY3/)

```
var date_regex = /^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])\/(19|20)\d{2}$/;
$('#BirthDate').blur(function () {
    if(date_regex.test(this.value)){
        alert('okay');
    }else{
        alert('Enter correct date');
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks, but please read question, it says, no read only, thanks :)

Comment: add the fiddle code to answer and I will accept it, thanks :)